# Javascript Date() function and GMT offset when converting string to date

Tags: javascript

I have noticed a peculiar behavior when converting strings to `Date` objects in javascript. When doing this:

```
var date1 = new Date("2014-09-28T00:00:00");
console.log(date1);
```

The result is:

```
Sun Sep 28 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Srednja Europa - ljet. vrij.)
```

The same code with another date.

```
var date2 = new Date("2014-10-28T00:00:00");
console.log(date2);
```

gives this result:

```
Tue Oct 28 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Srednja Europa - st. vrij.)
```

Notice that the GMT offset in the first variable is 2 hours and in the second just 1 hour. The first one takes the summertime time calculation in account and the second one does not. Can anybody explain this? Have to mention that I am from Croatia where the current GMT offset is plus two hours and summertime is on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/croatia/zagreb), Daylight Saving Time (DST) in Croatia ends on October 26th, 2014. Therefore, the first date (September 28th) includes it (GMT+2), and the second (October 28th) does not (GMT+1).

Comment: You are absolutely correct. All that confused me as I was using date1.getTime() == date2.getTime() to compare two dates. But as this is returned as a string with different GMT offsets, the strings did not match.

Comment: Well date1 == date2 does not seem function either. What is the correct way to compare two dates then?

Comment: The problem I have is that I create date1 as: var date1 = new Date("2014-09-28T00:00:00"); date1.setDate(date1.getDate() + 30) and then compare the result to another date. Though the date is now past October 26th the resulting date still carries GMT+02 instead of GMT+01.